# HTML apache rewrite to new directory

Tags: html, apache, redirect

I have been working on this for over an hour, and clearly I'm missing something.

I need to redirect:
www.site.com/directory/file.php?m=12345 to www.site.com/file2.php?m=12345

No matter what I am doing, the rule is not met, the data is missed or the redirect tries to go to the same directory.

I am doing the redirect in .htaccess.
The RewriteEngine is on and other redirects are working.
There is not a stop before the rewrite to prevent the rule from being read.
I am using these flags NC, R, L

DirectoryIndex Default3.php Default3.PHP

```
#Block listing of folder contents
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on
#Make access to image folder case insentive
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) Images/$1
RewriteRule ^common/(.*) Common/$1


#redirect old photo download page
RewriteRule GetZipPhotos.*(\d*) PhotoDownload.php?mls=$1 [NC,QAS,L]
```

Thanks for any help.

---

I have changed the .htaccess to

```
DirectoryIndex Default3.php Default3.PHP

#Block listing of folder contents
IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine on
#redirect old photo download page
RewriteRule ^Agents_Admin/GetZipPhotos.php(.*) /PhotoDownload.php$1 [R,NC,L]

#Make access to image folder case insentive
RewriteRule ^images/(.*) Images/$1
RewriteRule ^common/(.*) Common/$1`
```

The rewrite is still not working. According to the htaccess tester this does catch the original URL and should redirect correctly. But it is not. The original file keeps getting ran.

Comment: If you share your code, someone can try to help..

Comment: This is a one line statement, but here it is
RewriteRule file\.php\?\=*(\d*) file2.php?mls=$1 [NC,QAS,L]

Comment: That one line more helpful to solve than 10 lines of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^/Agents\_Admin/GetZipPhotos.php$ /PhotoDownload.php [R,NC,L,QSA]
```

QSA means Query String Append, in the (.*) and $1 are only URI parts, not parameters

Comment: That should work, but doesn't. Here is the rule modified to use the actual directory
    `RewriteRule ^/Agents\_Admin/GetZipPhotos.php(.*)$ /PhotoDownload.php$1 [R,NC,L]`